# Basic REST call to ml.google.com Predict endpoint

Tags: google-cloud-ml-engine

I'm trying to simply call to a REST API endpoint of a model I trained and I'm having issues. I keep called the endpoint and getting a 404.

Does someone know of a basic tutorial on how to just get this endpoint setup? I just want to run it in Postman and test it works so I can keep moving on my project.

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found my answer, hope this will be useful to someone else:

https://ml.googleapis.com/v1/projects/{projectname}/models/{modelname}/versions/{versionname}:predict

```
{projectname} - the name of your project, all lowercase
{modelname} - the name of your model, all lowercase
{versionname} - the name of your version, all lowercase
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing @tyler-findlay ; related to this, do you have an example of the request body (maybe even the full request sample)?